# Writing Another Text File based on Saved File from Tkinter

Tags: python, file, tkinter, dialog, save

I prompt the user to save a file, and I want to automatically save a file along with it. For example, let's say the user saves a text file under my program called "foo.txt", I want to automatically make a text file called "lengthfoo.txt". The word "length" before "foo", and ".txt" after "foo". Another example: when the user saves "HelloWorld.txt", I want the program to automatically save another file called "lengthHelloWorld.txt"

```
from ast import literal_eval
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *

def loadFile():
    try:
        save_file = askopenfile(mode='r', defaultextension=".zw")
        lengths_file = open("length%s.zw" % "origsavefilename", "r")
        with save_file as f:
            for line in f:
                rectList.extend(literal_eval(line.strip()))
        save_file.close()
        lengths_file.close()
        print "File Loaded"

def saveFile():
    try:
        save_file = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".zw")
        if save_file is not None:
            # Write the file to disk
            lengths_file = open("length%s.zw" % "origsavefilename", "w")
            save_file.close()
            print "File Saved Successfully."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `asksaveasfile`, but use `asksaveasfilename`, which returns the chosen file name instead of an opened file.

You can then create the file name with `length` using something like

```
import os

save_filename = asksaveasfilename()
save_filename_split = os.path.split(save_filename)
save_filename_length = os.path.join(save_filename_split[0],
                                     'length'+save_filename_split[-1])
```

Then you have the two file names which you can open and write stuff to.